# PHP interactive CLI: Up and Down arrows for history

Tags: php, command-line, readline

I am having a bug involving my php interactive CLI program.

I add commands to the history using readline_add_history, and read them in using readline.

The bug is that if, using the up arrow key, I scroll through the history to a command 5 characters or longer, the first character of the command "sticks", and will stay there, after I keep using the arrow keys to scroll again. It disappears only after I hit enter.

Eg:

```
% hello
<enter>
%
<up arrow key>
% hello
<down arrow key>
% h
<up arrow key>
% hhello
<down arrow key>
% h
<enter>
%
<up arrow key>
% hello
** notice here that the extra h isn't read in as a command. **
```

Where can I view the code involving the arrow keys / command history? I've looked online for resources on how readline handles the arrow keys and history but I can't find anything.

My code is like this:

```
while(true)
{

$command = readline( "\n%" );

.. do stuff ..

readline_add_history( $command );

}
```

I also have a readline_completion_function but it isn't being called when I use the arrow keys.

Comment: I'd guess it's in sapi/cli/php_cli.c

Comment: Any ideas on why it would print only the first character, and only for commands 5 chars or longer?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with readline() and the prompt field (tested with PHP 5.5.9 Ubuntu), if the prompt field has 'non-printable' characters in it, like \n, that you have used.

I was having similar problems, when trying to used ESC codes to color the prompt, it just causes the history function to go haywire :(

Example: $_command = readline("\033[32m PHP> \033[35m");

The prompt can only have normal chars in it, if you want the history function to work correctly, unfortunately.